# Puppeteer - Request Interception postData not overriding

Tags: node.js, request, puppeteer

Hi I've got this request i'm trying to intercept and override its postData.

Here's my method of doing it:

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);

var staticWebPayloadData = {"sensor_data": "temperatureReading&70deg"};

 page.on('request', req => {
  if (req.url().includes('staticweb')){
    req.continue({
      'postData': JSON.stringify(staticWebPayloadData)
    });
  }
  else{
    req.continue();
  }
});
```

But it doesn't work. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you describe what doesn't work? What does the original request look like and what response or error are you getting? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
await page.route('staticweb/**', route => {
  if (route.request().postData().includes('my-string'))
    route.fulfill({ body: 'mocked-data' });
  else
    route.continue();
});
```